# Build Maven plugins using Gradle

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, gradle

I am thinking about moving to Gradle. I do, however, have some Maven plugins that will need to be supported for the foreseeable future.

Is there a way to build Maven plugins using Gradle?

Answer (score 5):

[Here's something](https://github.com/evgeny-goldin/build-info/blob/3712d354f31d813c18c10a35dc07e9581979e61f/build.gradle#L360) that worked for me:

- After compiling plugin's sources generate project's POM: `"install.repositories.mavenInstaller.pom.writeTo( 'pom.xml' )"`
- Patch POM generated and provide plugin's coordinates and correct destination directories
- Run `"mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor"`

This way `"build/classes/main/META-INF/maven/plugin.xml"` is created and then packed properly by `jar` task, which is all that's needed for a jar file to become a Maven plugin, AFAIK. Also, I believe, ["maven-plugin-annotations"](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) should be used in a plugin.

```
task pluginDescriptor( type: Exec ) {
    commandLine 'mvn', '-e', '-B', 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor'
    doFirst {
        final File pom = project.file( 'pom.xml' )
        install.repositories.mavenInstaller.pom.writeTo( pom )
        assert pom.file, "[$pom.canonicalPath] was not created"

        pom.text = pom.text.
            replace( '<groupId>unknown</groupId>',             "<groupId>${project.group}</groupId>" ).
            replace( '<artifactId>empty-project</artifactId>', "<artifactId>${project.name}</artifactId>" ).
            replace( '<version>0</version>',                   """
                                                              |<version>${version}</version>
                                                              |  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
                                                              |  <build>
                                                              |    <directory>\${project.basedir}/build</directory>
                                                              |    <outputDirectory>\${project.build.directory}/classes/main</outputDirectory>
                                                              |  </build>
                                                              |""".stripMargin().trim())
    }
    doLast {
        final  pluginDescriptor = new File(( File ) project.compileGroovy.destinationDir, 'META-INF/maven/plugin.xml' )
        assert pluginDescriptor.file, "[$pluginDescriptor.canonicalPath] was not created"
        println "Plugin descriptor file:$pluginDescriptor.canonicalPath is created successfully"
    }
}

project.compileGroovy.doLast{ pluginDescriptor.execute() }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Based on this I made the following version that does not need the replace: https://gist.github.com/fikovnik/ffc1fed1867bc7fa679aaf8e48f00c21

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a third-party Gradle plugin that allows to build Maven plugins. One possibility would be to call into Maven to do part of the work (in particular the metadata generation). The necessary POM could be created on the fly. Another possibility would be to commit the metadata to source control and update it manually (possibly by running Maven when needed). Last but not least you could write some code that performs the metadata generation on the Gradle side, possibly reusing some Maven code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Gradle Plugin that can be used create Maven Plugin
[Maven Plugin Builder Gradle Plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/maven-plugin-builder-gradle-plugin) but I have yet to get it to work

Answer (score -1):

At the moment that feature is not supported but it's on the [development roadmap](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/deep_import_of_maven_projects). Check the [roadmap dashboard](http://www.gradle.org/roadmap) every once in a while to see if the status changed.

Comment: Our focus is more on supporting the _reuse_ of Maven plugins from Gradle, rather than supporting to _build_ them.

Comment: roadmap dashboard link is no longer active